# Simple new + then for Q promises

Tags: promise, q

I'm trying to use `Q` Promise implementation, but am facing strange inconsistency.

When I run in Chrome m33, the following code:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(1);
}).then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

It works just as I expect - it returns another `Promise` and logs `1`.

But if I call the same code wrapped into `(function (Promise) { ... }(window.Q));`, I see body of `resolve` callback in console, instead of a value.

[Fiddle to look at](http://jsfiddle.net/a5h6R/2/) - works in Chrome and Aurora.

Am I missing something or is it a bug in the library?

PS: `Q` version `1.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Q v1.0.1 which introduces `Q.Promise`, which supports a common subset of the ES6 promise interface. `Q` is analogous to `Promise.resolve` and `new Promise` replaces the erstwhile `Q.defer()`. ES6 did not lift the Q API exactly, but did largely lift the behavior of the analogous functions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks, like `Q.promise` is a replacement for native `Promise`, not the `Q` itself: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5h6R/3/).

It's very strange, though. I can't migrate to native promises w/o changing the code later.
Cause `Q.promise` -> `Promise`, but `Q.all` -> `Promise.all`.